# How to prevent the combination of \smash with \intertext causing an unacceptable situation

Tags: underbrace, intertext

```
& = \frac 1 {2\pi i} \int\limits_C \frac{f(w)}{w-a}
\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{z-a}{w-a} \right)^n \, dw \\[8pt]
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1 {2\pi i} \int\limits_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}}
\cdot {} \underbrace{(z-a)^n}_{\begin{smallmatrix} \text{No ``$w$''} \\
\text{appears} \\ \text{here!} \end{smallmatrix}} \, dw
\intertext{The absence of ``$w$'' from the expression over this
$\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ justifies the next step.}
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \,  \smash[b]{\underbrace{ \frac 1 {2\pi i}
\int\limits_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}} \, dw}_{\begin{smallmatrix}
\text{No ``$z$''} \\ \text{appears} \\ \text{here!}
\end{smallmatrix}}} \, \right) (z-a)^n
\intertext{The absence of ``$z$'' from the expression over this
$\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ justifies this next step.}
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n.
```

The use of `\smash[b]{}` is intended to make the delimiters have the size that would be appropriate if the underbrace were not there, and it does that.

HOWEVER, the line below that in `\intertext{}` runs straight through that small matrix, an obviously abominable result.

How can I make this work as intended, without doing anything too complicated or offending the gods of LaTeX?

Comment: (I haven't tested this, but have used the technique in the past.)  Presumably the reason you've `\smash`ed the underbraced material is to avoid overly large parentheses with `\left` and `\right`.  Outside the scope of the parens, add a `\vphantom` that will reproduce the depth of that component.  (You could actually use the same code that sets the underbrace, but usually something simpler suffices.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\left`...`\right` constructions, use `\biggl`...`\biggr` pairs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  & = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_C \frac{f(w)}{w - a}
    \cdot \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \biggl( \frac{z - a}{w - a} \biggr)^n \, \mathrm{d}w \\[8pt]
  & = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_C \frac{f(w)}{(w - a)^{n + 1}}
    \cdot \underbrace{(z - a)^n}_{\substack{\text{No ``$w$''} \\ \text{appears} \\ \text{here!} }} \, \mathrm{d}w
\intertext{The absence of ``$w$'' from the expression over this $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ justifies the next step.}
  & = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \biggl( \underbrace{ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}
    \int\limits_C \frac{f(w)}{(w - a)^{n + 1}} \, \mathrm{d}w}_{\substack{\text{No ``$z$''} \\ \text{appears} \\ \text{here!}}} \biggr) (z - a)^n
\intertext{The absence of ``$z$'' from the expression over this $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ justifies this next step.}
  & = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_n (z - a)^n.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```